# Can someone explain Groovy command chain dsl example in documentation... the text got parsed into maps and closures

Tags: groovy, dsl

```
show = { println it }
square_root = { Math.sqrt(it) }

def please(action) {
  [the: { what ->
    [of: { n -> action(what(n)) }]
  }]
}

// equivalent to: please(show).the(square_root).of(100)

please show the square_root of 100
// ==> 10.0
```

I understand `please(show)` returns an object which has a method called `the(param)` which in turn returns an object which has a method `of(param)`.

what i dont understand is how the line

```
please show the square_root of 100
```

got converted to maps and closures after `please(show)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is to write the code out without the "optional" calls and
member access missing.  That is:

```
please(show).the(square_root).of(100)
```

The way this then was made to work, is to chain the next call by returning a map, with (at
least) a key "in the sentence", that again has a closure as value to
continue this chain.

So to write that out even more verbose (for one
link in the chain):

```
.getAt('the').call(square_root)
```

Comment: Thank you i think i am beginning to understand.
So please(show) returns a map and with .getAt() of Groovy Maps (with string as default keys) we get 'the' key value which is a closure which is then called with call()